# Keras model.predict_on_batch slows down significantly with large dataset

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, keras, tf.keras

I am trying to generate predictions on a dataset with >2million rows. 
`model.predict_on_batch()` takes significantly longer predicting on 2million rows.

This code is based on Keras [`model.fit_generator`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training_generator.py#L23) implementation.

```py
from my_sequence import MyCustomDataSequence
from keras.utils.data_utils import OrderedEnqueuer
import logging
from tqdm import tqdm
import keras
import sys
import time
import numpy as np

#This data frame is ~2.6GB
df=pd.read_csv('data.csv')
data_df['pred'] = None
my_seq = MyCustomDataSequence(df, batch_size=8)
enqueuer.start(workers=12, max_queue_size=12)
output_generator = enqueuer.get()
w_time_arr = []
p_time_arr = []
steps = len(my_seq)
pbar = tqdm(total=steps, desc="Generating Predictions", file=sys.stdout)
    try:
        for i in range(steps):
            get_batch_start_time = time.time()
            x, Y = next(output_generator)
            w_time_arr.append(time.time() - get_batch_start_time)
            get_prediction_start_time = time.time()
            pred=model.predict_on_batch(x)
            p_time_arr.append(time.time() - get_prediction_start_time)
            #Do stuff with prediction result
            pbar.update()
            pbar.set_description(
                "Generating Predictions | Get Batch time Last {:.5} Mean {:.5}. Prediction Time Last {:.5} Average {:.5}. Queue Size {}".format(w_time_arr[-1], np.mean(w_time_arr), p_time_arr[-1], np.mean(p_time_arr), enqueuer.queue.qsize()))
    finally:
        if enqueuer is not None:
            enqueuer.stop()
```

When I run this code with ~40000 rows it takes about ~1.5seconds/iteration. When I read the entire dataset (>2million rows) then it takes more than 5seconds/iteration.

I added additional code to track `next(output_generator)` and `model.predict_on_batch(x)` time. `next(output_generator)` time stays constant at ~0.1 second. However, `model.predict_on_batch(x)` time increases as I load more rows into DataFrame. Note that I am not changing `batch_size`, `worker_count` or `max_queue_size`.

Any insights would be appreciated.

---

Some additional information that may be helpful.

```sh
$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2017 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Sep__1_21:08:03_CDT_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 9.0, V9.0.176

$ pip3 show keras
Name: Keras
Version: 2.2.0

$ pip3 show tensorflow-gpu
Name: tensorflow-gpu
Version: 1.8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try out a few optimization techniques and parallelize your code execution.

A couple of things that you can try out are:

- Setting OMP_NUM_THREADS
- Horovodization
- Thread Pooling

Comment: None of these options are relevant to the context of the question

Answer (score 0):

You could try using some tools for faster inference, like [TensorRT](https://developer.nvidia.com/tensorrt) or [OpenVINO](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_install_guides_overview.html).

I'm presenting the OpenVINO approach below as I work on it. OpenVINO optimizes your model by converting to Intermediate Representation (IR), performing graph pruning and fusing some operations into others while preserving accuracy. Then it uses vectorization in runtime. So finally you have better performance. OpenVINO is optimized for Intel hardware but it should work with any CPU.

It's rather straightforward to convert the Keras model to OpenVINO. The full tutorial on how to do it can be found [here](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino_notebooks/tree/main/notebooks/101-tensorflow-to-openvino). Some snippets are below.

**Install OpenVINO**

The easiest way to do it is using PIP. Alternatively, you can use [this tool](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/openvino-toolkit/download.html) to find the best way in your case.

```
pip install openvino-dev[tensorflow2]
```

**Save your model as SavedModel**

OpenVINO is not able to convert the HDF5 model, so you have to save it as SavedModel first.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from custom_layer import CustomLayer
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model.h5', custom_objects={'CustomLayer': CustomLayer})
tf.saved_model.save(model, 'model')
```

**Use Model Optimizer to convert SavedModel model**

The Model Optimizer is a command-line tool that comes from OpenVINO Development Package. It converts the Tensorflow model to IR, a default format for OpenVINO. You can also try the precision of FP16, which should give you better performance without a significant accuracy drop (change data_type). Run in the command line:

```
mo --saved_model_dir "model" --data_type FP32 --output_dir "model_ir"
```

**Run the inference**

The converted model can be loaded by the runtime and compiled for a specific device, e.g., CPU or GPU (integrated into your CPU like Intel HD Graphics). If you don't know what the best choice for you is, use AUTO. I assume your processing is batch processing, so I suggest adding a performance hint (as shown below) to use the device that fulfills your requirement.

```
# Load the network
ie = Core()
model_ir = ie.read_model(model="model_ir/model.xml")
compiled_model_ir = ie.compile_model(model=model_ir, device_name="AUTO", config={"PERFORMANCE_HINT":"CUMULATIVE_THROUGHPUT"}) # alternatively just THROUGHPUT

# Get output layer
output_layer_ir = compiled_model_ir.output(0)

# Run inference on the input image
result = compiled_model_ir([input_image])[output_layer_ir]
```

Disclaimer: I work on OpenVINO.